# viewport width not working with android

Tags: android, iphone, width, meta-tags, viewport

I have searched a lot for making my site stretching 100% of the width and it worked but it just broke randomly. The site works find on the iPhone but it has issues with android phones. Oddly, the site extends further than the device width.

I am using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />` right now and the site is at mallsear.ch

Anyone have an idea?
Thanks!

Edit: I have this in CSS too:

```
html{
    color: white;
    background: #1f1f1f;
    font-family: Futura;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

So I finally found the problem. The `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in the Facebook connect stretched out the site and once I deleted it, it was fixed.

Hope this can help someone!

Comment: OMG,you man is a life savior! I've been searching and testing every solution for days,yes the issue was cause by that div and I solved the issue by adding style="display:none".